# Drupal 7.59 images not download in android app

Tags: android, image, drupal-7, android-image, drupal-services

I have update my drupal version from 7.4 to 7.59.
after that i can able to see my image files in browser, but i cannot download thoese image via my Android apps. It was working fine in my old drupal version

can you please suggest any solution regarding this?

Comment: You have modules like `filefield_paths` or a media library ? Ensure version about all module who deals with image. Check you jquery version too , maybe you need to change it

Comment: @Fky Thanks, I have created the json document format View, Images as fields it look like "image" : {
          "src" : "http://specialapps.in/sites/default/files/IMG_206.JPG",
          "alt" : ""
        },
but i need direct link, Can you please help us.

Comment: What do you mean by "direct link" ?

Comment: @Fky I need just URL alone without src, alt keyword. . Its look like "image":"url"